# OpenCV VideoCapture returns strange frame offset for different versions

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I'm using `opencv-python` and when I execute the following code:

```
index = 0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
while True:
    offset = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
    print(cv2.__version__, index, offset)

    ok, frame = cap.read()
    if not ok:
        break
    index += 1
```

I get the following output:

```
3.4.7 0 0.0
3.4.7 1 33.36666666666667
3.4.7 2 66.73333333333333
3.4.7 3 100.10000000000001
3.4.7 4 133.46666666666667
```

If I execute this code on version `3.4.8.29`, I get the following output:

```
3.4.8 0 0.0
3.4.8 1 0.0
3.4.8 2 33.36666666666667
3.4.8 3 66.73333333333333
3.4.8 4 100.10000000000001
```

And if I execute it on version `4.5.2.52` I get:

```
4.5.2 0 0.0
4.5.2 1 0.0
4.5.2 2 0.0
4.5.2 3 0.0
4.5.2 4 0.0
```

The question is first of all, which one is the correct one? It seems like 3.4.7 is correct, but it also seems to be changing randomly between versions.

And also how can I modify the other versions to get the proper result, same as `3.4.7`

Comment: You may use FFprobe (command line tool) for extracting the PTS timestamps as described [here](https://superuser.com/a/842397/635712). `ffprobe -i vid.mp4 -show_frames -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time -of csv=p=0 > frames.txt`

Comment: Can you test whether newer versions read some empty frames? Then all version might be correct for readable non-empty frames.

Comment: @Rotem this is the result of what you suggested:  0.000000
0.033367
0.066733
0.100100

Comment: @micka what do you mean by an "empty frame"?

Comment: Size of the image is 0 width and height.

Comment: @Micka no, the images are of normal size

Comment: Can you upload the video?

Comment: I hope that's fine. It's not the exact same video, but here as well there are 4 frames, and the values are completely inconsistent between versions. https://www.dropbox.com/s/pndjzwx67ondptl/GPFR0115.MP4?dl=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read the OpenCV docs and they said: "Reading / writing properties involves many layers. Some unexpected result might happens along this chain. Effective behaviour depends from device hardware, driver and API Backend." (source: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.15/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#gaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704d)

So in other words OpenCV does not guaranty consistent and reliable behavior of this function.

Also I installed openCV 4.5.2.52 and applied your script to one of my '.mp4' videos. Then I got the same result as you had for openCV version 3.4.8.29. So I think the behaviour you experience is not a 'bug', but rather the unreliable behavior of this function.

As work around you can compute the "offset" by dividing the frame number by the FPS count (see code below). Then you have more control over the behaviour and maybe more consisted results.

```
index = 0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
while True:
    offset = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)

    ok, frame = cap.read()
    if not ok:
        break
    
    # CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC
    print("CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC: ", index, offset)
    
    # Devide fps by frame number
    offset = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) / fps * 1000
    print("cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES", index, offset)
     
    index += 1
```

Comment: please change your code to mention that offset should be `offset = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) / fps * 1000`. Unless there will a better answer explaining the issue I will mark this as correct in the next few days.

Comment: tnx for the feedback! I changed the example code :)

Comment: @user972014 Does this satisfy your answer? or is there anything else you need?

Comment: Be careful using the frame number and the fps rate to calculate the frame times as there are rare cases of video files with variable frame rates (videos where the fps is not stable or constant).